# How to refresh a XAML window after changing the data in code behind?

Tags: c#, xaml

I develop a GUI for an embedded MC.The MC stors its configuartion in a 256 byte EEPROM, and the data a transferred via RS232/USB into a C# application.

In the C# application I use an array

```
        public static byte[] Eeprom = new byte[258]
          { 32,   1,   0,   9,   3,   7,   0,   3, 
             1, 204,   3, 255,  50,  50,  18,   0, 
             2,   3,   1,   0,   2,   1,   0,   0,}; //etc., not all lines showed here
```

to store the date. The code shows the default values, which are overwritten when the MC is read.
To display this raw-data in XAML the bytes are sorted in data structures. For example line 3 of the field, starting at `Eeprom[16]` is converted like this:

```
   public class Hardware{
   public List<SchaltAusgang> Schalter = new();

   public void SetUp(byte[] Eprom){

            for (int i = 0; i < AnzahlKanal +1; i++)
            {
                zeile = (i + offset) * zeilenlaenge;
                    if (Schalter.Count == i)
                    {
                        Schalter.Add(new SchaltAusgang { 
                            Typ =(Ausgang)Eprom[zeile], 
                              // more data
                            PWM = Eprom[zeile + 5] }); 
                    } else
                    {
                        Schalter[i].Typ = (Ausgang)Eprom[zeile];
                              // more data
                        Schalter[i].PWM = Eprom[zeile + 5];
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

When `SetUp()` is called the first time a new list is generated and filled with default values. When I call `SetUp()` the next time, after reading from seriell port, I only change the values.

When I first call it the data are correctly displayed:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
       Hardware Board = new ();
       SerPort SerPort = new (); 
       public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SerPort.InitSeriell();
            Board.SetUp(SerPort.Eeprom );
            lstSchalter.ItemsSource = Board.Schalter;
        }
     }
```

But after updating the data by reading from `SerPort` the XAML Display doesn't change, also the data are changed as I can verify holding while debuging:

```
        private void ButReadEprom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerPort.OpenSeriell();
            SerPort.ReadEprom();
            SerPort.CloseSeriell();  // Data are transferred correctly

            Board.SetUp(SerPort.Eeprom);
            txtBeschreibung.Text = Board.Beschreibung; // this is updated correctly!
            lstSchalter.ItemsSource = Board.Schalter; // when the debugger stops here the data in Board.Schalter are correct!
        }
```

The XAML Code for the data is:

```
        <StackPanel Name="lstName" >
            <TextBox  Name="txtBeschreibung" />
        </StackPanel>

<ListBox  Name="lstSchalter">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <!-- more definitions -->
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBox  Text="{Binding Typ}"/>
                        <!-- more data -->
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding PWM}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Do I have to refresh something? Or any other idear?
Thank you!

Comment: [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0). Also a small tip: using `Window` Constructor to execute a custom code isn't a good idea. Use `Window.Loaded` Event handler instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need refresh listbox after changes.

```
lstSchalter.ItemsSource = Board.Schalter;
lstSchalter.Items.Refresh();
```

Or use [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-5.0)

MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<SchaltAusgang> Items {get; set;} = new();

    Hardware Board = new ();
    SerPort SerPort = new (); 
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SerPort.InitSeriell();
        Board.SetUp(SerPort.Eeprom );
        lstSchalter.ItemsSource = Items;
        foreach(var item in Board.Schalter)
        {
            Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

when you change collection `Items` it refresh automatically

```
private void ButReadEprom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SerPort.OpenSeriell();
    SerPort.ReadEprom();
    SerPort.CloseSeriell();  // Data are transferred correctly

    Board.SetUp(SerPort.Eeprom);
    txtBeschreibung.Text = Board.Beschreibung;  
    Items.Clear();
    foreach(var item in Board.Schalter)
    {
        Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Ididn't find the method `lstSchalter.refresh();` . I installed NuGet package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms and added `using System.Windows.Forms;`, but the method was not visible.

Comment: Not work `lstSchalter.refresh();` or `lstSchalter.Refresh();`?
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms` and `using System.Windows.Forms` different things.

Comment: Both. IntelliSens doesn't find the method. I guess the .dll is missing.

Comment: @Bernd Update answer.